Не понимаю как определить значение на указанной позиции Numpy
Дана задача: Зафиксируйте состояние генератора случайных чисел с помощью NumPy-функции random.seed(). Аргумент функции совпадает с номером варианта. Сгенерируйте одномерный массив из 1000 значений (закон распределения и его параметры: равномерное с параметрами 0, 1), поместите его в переменную x. Преобразуйте массив x в массив заданной размерности: 4×50×5. Определите значение на указанной позиции: строка два, столбец одиннадцать, третья координата четыре. Значение при выводе округлите до 2 знаков с помощью NumPy-функции round(). Для вывода используйте функцию print().
Прописал код:
np.random.seed(12)
w = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 1000)
x = w.reshape(4, 50, 5)
y = x[1, 10, 2]
z = np.round(y, 2)
print(z)

Проверяющая программа не принимает ответ, я так понял проблема в "строка два, столбец одиннадцать, третья координата четыре" и строке y = x[1, 10, 2], но в таком случае не понимаю как указать нужные значения?

Ну так 3-я координата четыре, а у вас 3, нужно y = x[1, 10, 3] (Если в задании конечно от 1 нумерация).

По всей видимости нумерация была от 1, спасибо огромное, помогло
